# Java based blog website framework - Apache Roller?

Tags: java, content-management-system, blogs, blog-engine

I'm a java developer and I am planning to implement a java based blog style website.  I'm considering using Apache Roller as the framework for the website and was curious if there were other suggestions or feedback on Roller.  These are some basic requirements:

- Need to support multiple authors for articles
- Search engine friendly
- Framework needs to be customizable (both client side and server side)
- Open source framework desired

Comment: Roller had a couple of security vulnerabilities involving cross-site scripting, recently. I don't know if all of them had been fixed...

Comment: I believe all of security vulnerabilities that have been reported are fixed in the current release.

Answer (score 3):

I decided to move forward with Vosao CMS (http://www.vosao.org/) on Google App Engine because I'm looking for the lowest possible start up cost.